# Does linq not work off of a IList? Want to see if collection of type T contains a particular entry

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of

```
IList<Products>
```

And I want to see if the collection contains the product where

product.Key == "ABC"

Comment: let's see your sample code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method:

```
bool b = list.Any(x => x.Key == "ABC");
```

Answer (score 2):

It does, it's generally called LINQ to Objects when used that way.

If you don't have it, you would need:

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of the file to get access to the extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Linq works on IList as well? What's the problem with you're code?